# Are there any good "dispersion blur" image filters?

Tags: image-processing, blur

I would like to obtain an effect where pixels get spreaded locally. I tried to reproduce how such a filter would look, I hope you get the idea:

before:

[image: before]

after:

[image: after]

Note: here I ran a blur, aded noise and then added a lot of contrast to give a "spreading effect" and remove the noise in plain areas. But it wouldn't work with not-extreme colours (in the sense of contrast).

Edit: now that I've found the answer, here the official definition for the filter which describes best the effect:

> The Spread filter swaps each pixel in the active layer or selection
>   with another randomly chosen pixel by a user specified amount. It
>   works on color transitions, not on plain color areas. **No new color is
>   introduced**.
>
> http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/plug-in-spread.html

Comment: This appears to be a dither rather than a blur.

Comment: It is unclear what you want.  How is simple low pass filtering not what you are asking for?

Comment: What software are you interested in?

Comment: @Unapiedra : mostly free ones (Gimp, Paint.net), but if it's only available on photoshop, I'll find a way.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : sorry for the unclearness, I'm far from an expert in photo edition. Thanks to AJ I checked the dither wikipedia and I think a blur + random dither would be close from what I want

Comment: This question went through a round of edits here, so let me ask to make sure I understand the original intent -- what you'd like is a border where pixels from one side of the image blend in a pixelated way into the other, not necessarily a smooth blend as implied by blur?

Comment: Also, could you perhaps show what you are looking for with a sample photograph rather than colored scribbles?

Comment: @mattdm Not being a native english speaker, I had a lot of trouble wording this question. If I could have done it with a photograph, I would not have need to ask the question first. Anyway, I find the solution and posted it down here, the "scatter" filter in gimp is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, bu having seen that, I still don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Basically, you just want a ragged, pixelated edge?

Comment: @mattdm I needed a whole ragged and pixelated picture, not just the edges. but without knowing which filter to use, I could only make a preview with black and white edges. Also, some editors changed "spreaded" by "blurred" which may have added to the confusion. I wanted a "random spread" of the pixel, which kind of "blur" the image, like in the link I provided.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking all this because I'm wondering if we should edit "blurred" back to be something like "scattered".

Answer (score 3):

Well, finally I've found it in Gimp (french version).

Filtre > Bruit > Eparpiller (Filters > Noise > <s>Scatter</s> EDIT: [Spread](http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/plug-in-spread.html)  )

[image]

"Mélanger" et "Piquer" are good too(not sure the translations, maybe "melt" and "pick"). Can't believe I missed them.